# SQL Server get a group of 10 elements from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm developing an EPG for a TV. I need to show epg of 10 channels in each page. I need to get data from SQL Server. Make a call to server get channels from 0 - 9 than user might decide to change page which for me means I should make an other call to server to get channels from 10 - 19, next page 20 - 29 and so on. The question is how do I get group data like that in SQL Server?

```
id channelNr description shortname starttime andtime
0  100        desc1       tv1       10:10:00 10:40:00
1  101        desc2       tv2       10:40:00 12:40:00
```

this is how my table looks like, but more rows

Comment: What does your table look like? What queries have you tried and where exactly are you going wrong?

Comment: i know how to get top 10 but i dont know how to next 10 element from sqlserver. a sec im posting my table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this - a CTE (Common Table Expression) that returns the data you need, plus a `RowNum` column that defines a row number; then you can just pick `WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 9` first, then `WHERE RowNum BETWEEN 10 AND 19` for the second page etc.

Since you want to select *the first 10* rows, that `RowNum` column must have some ordering criteria - e.g. your "channel number" or whatever makes sense to you (I just picked `BirthDate DESC` here as a demo).

This sample here is based on the AdventureWorks sample database - you'll need to adapt it to your own needs and your table / columns:

```
;WITH PagedResults AS
(
    SELECT
        e.BusinessEntityID ,
        e.NationalIDNumber ,
        e.OrganizationLevel ,
        e.JobTitle ,
        e.BirthDate ,
        e.HireDate ,
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY BirthDate DESC)
    FROM
        HumanResources.Employee e
)
SELECT
    *
FROM    
    PagedResults
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN 0 AND 9
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `OFFSET-FETCH` clause of SQL SERVER.
OFFSET specifies how many rows to skip and FETCH specifies how many rows to select after skipping the number of rows specified in OFFSET.

Comment: OFFSET-FETCH is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and therefore not available to the OP which uses the **2008** version.....

Comment: im using Sql Server 2008